# GitLab fatal: unable to access : The requested URL returned error: 503

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

While trying to fetch/push/pull the git repository, it throws 503 error.

*Using TortoiseGit*

git.exe fetch -v --progress "origin"

`fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab.foo.com/group/repository.git/': The requested URL returned error: 503`

*Using GitBash*

`fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab.foo.com/group/repository.git/': The requested URL returned error: 503`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having the thought, HTTP 503 is "service unavailable", and under error category *5XX* it could be server issue. But the service was accesible on browser (80). We eventually looked multiple possible (routing, firewall, dns) option on gitlab server, but no luck.
Noticeably I was behind the corporate proxy server. The solution was lying locally with machine, having proxy `SYSTEM VARIABLE` / `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE`, which was overridding the gitconfig settings.

I removed proxy [system variables](http://kumar.swatantra.info/where-is-environment-variables/), and it started working. Possible system variables to look for and delete it. 
`http_proxy`
`https_proxy`
`HTTP_PROXY`
`HTTPS_PROXY`

You may also set `no_proxy` to gitlab URL.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that you have an existing git config file with proxy settings in it.

Try to delete this file or move it to another location to make sure that is the problem.