# How to retrieve the star counts in GitLab Python API?

Tags: gitlab, python-gitlab

I try to request the number of stars and commits of a public software repository in GitLab using its [Python client](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io). However, I keep getting `GitlabHttpError 503` if executing the following script.

```
import gitlab
import requests

url = 'https://gitlab.com/juliensimon/huggingface-demos'
private_token = 'xxxxxxxx'

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url, private_token=private_token)
all_projects = gl.projects.list(all=True)
```

I read the previous posts but none of them works for me: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066100/git-pull-error-the-requested-url-returned-error-503-while-accessing), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066100/git-pull-error-the-requested-url-returned-error-503-while-accessing), and [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992851/gitlab-fatal-unable-to-access-the-requested-url-returned-error-503). People mentioned:

1. Retrying later usually works `[I tried in different periods but still got the same error.]`
2. Setting an environment variable for `no_proxy` `[Not sure what it means for me? I do not set the proxy explicitly.]`

Comment: The URL shall instead be the hosting website you want to inquiry about. I finally got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 503 response is telling you something - your base URL is off. You only need to provide the base GitLab URL so the client makes requests against its `api/v4/` endpoint.

Either use `https://gitlab.com` only, so that the client will correctly call `https://gitlab.com/api/v4` endpoints (instead of trying `https://gitlab.com/juliensimon/huggingface-demos/api/v4` as it does now), or skip it entirely when using GitLab.com if you're on python-gitlab 3.0.0 or later.

```py
# Explicit gitlab.com
url = 'https://gitlab.com'

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url, private_token=private_token)

# Or just use the default for GitLab.com (python-gitlab 3.0.0+ required)
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(private_token=private_token)
```

Edit: The original question was about the 503, but the comment to my answer is a follow-up on how to get project details. Here's the full snippet, which also fetches the token from the environment instead:

```py
import os
import gitlab

private_token = os.getenv("GITLAB_PRIVATE_TOKEN")

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(private_token=private_token)
project = gl.projects.get("juliensimon/huggingface-demos")

print(project.forks_count)
print(project.star_count)
```

Comment: How can I retrieve a public repository's metadata such as star_count and fork_count? For example: https://gitlab.com/juliensimon/huggingface-demos

Comment: @JimmyZhao that feels like a follow-up question but I've edited my answer to add that. See above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that quite answers my post!